# WebAPI PushStreamContent client read video stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, video-streaming

I have a camera that i expose via a webapi. This camera returns jpeg frames. On the server side i use the following method:

```
[Route("api/v1/camera/live/stream")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetStream()
{
    logger.Trace($"GET api/v1/camera/live/stream called");

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
    response.Content = new PushStreamContent(new Action<Stream, HttpContent, TransportContext>(async (stream, content, tansportContext) =>
    {
        EventHandler<AcquiredDataEventArgs<CameraFrame>> handler = (_, __) => { };
        try
        {
            MjpegWriter writer = new MjpegWriter(stream);
            handler = (s, e) => writer.Write(e.Data.Image.GetJpegStream());

            camera.DataAcquired += handler;
            while (HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }
            camera.DataAcquired -= handler;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error($"Streaming error", ex);
            throw;
        }
        logger.Trace("streaming ended");

    }));

    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--boundary");

    return response;
}
```

I would like to show this video stream live in a WPF application.
If i open the video stream via a web browser it nicely streams the video... but how do i stream to a c# client application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lib (available via nuget) Emgu.CV is an C# wrapper on OpenCV and can receive the stream.

```
using Emgu.CV;

...

    private void StartWatching()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                capture = new VideoCapture(headConfiguration.CameraStreamingUri.ToString());
                capture.ImageGrabbed += Capture_ImageGrabbed;
                capture.Start(ExceptionHandler.AlwaysHandle);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                capture = null;
                Logger.Error(ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        });
    }

    private void Capture_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (capture == null || OnNewCameraFrame == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var frame = new Mat();
            if (capture.Retrieve(frame))
            {
                var output = new ByteImage(frame.Width, frame.Height, frame.Step);

                Marshal.Copy(frame.DataPointer, output.Data, 0, output.Height * output.Stride);

                OnNewCameraFrame?.Invoke(this, new ValueChangeArgs<ByteImage>(output));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use HttpClient for this. Just make sure you do not buffer the response by setting `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://...",
    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
using (Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
{
    // Do whatever with the resulting stream.
}
```